# Loop through NSDictionary to create separate NSArrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a large `NSDictionary` that I need to loop through and create separate `NSArray`s.  Here are the contents:

```
(
        {
        id =         {
            text = "";
        };
        sub =         {
            text = " , ";
        };
        text = "";
        "thumb_url" =         {
            text = "";
        };
        title =         {
            text = "2010-2011";
        };
        type =         {
            text = "title";
        };
    },
        {
        id =         {
            text = "76773";
        };
        sub =         {
            text = "December 13, 2010";
        };
        text = "";
        "thumb_url" =         {
            text = "http://www.puc.edu/__data/assets/image/0004/76774/varieties/thumb.jpg";
        };
        title =         {
            text = "College Days - Fall 2010";
        };
        type =         {
            text = "gallery";
        };
    },
        {
        id =         {
            text = "";
        };
        sub =         {
            text = "";
        };
        text = "";
        "thumb_url" =         {
            text = "";
        };
        title =         {
            text = "2009-2010";
        };
        type =         {
            text = "title";
        };
    },
        {
        id =         {
            text = "76302";
        };
        sub =         {
            text = "December 3, 2010";
        };
        text = "";
        "thumb_url" =         {
            text = "http://www.puc.edu/__data/assets/image/0019/76303/varieties/thumb.jpg";
        };
        title =         {
            text = "Christmas Colloquy";
        };
        type =         {
            text = "gallery";
        };
    }
)
```

Each section has a type key, which I need to check.  When it finds the `title` key, I need to add those to an array.  Then the next sections that would use the `gallery` key needs to be in its own array until it finds another `title` key.  Then the `gallery` keys after that into their own array.

I am using a `UITableView` section titles and content.  So, the `NSDictionary` above should have one `NSArray *titles;` array, and two other arrays each containing the galleries that came after the title.

I have tried using a `for` loop but I just can't seem to get it right.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear by your log, but I'm guessing your `NSDictionary` has values of `NSDictionary`? If so:

```
NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];
// etc.

for (id key in sourceDictionary) {
  NSDictionary *subDictionary = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
  if ([subDictionary objectForKey:@"type"] == @"title")
    [titles addObject:[subDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
  // etc.
}
```

Your question is a bit unclear... but this is how you would properly loop through an `NSDictionary`.

EDIT:

```
NSMutableDictionary *galleries = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *currentTitle;

for (id key in sourceDictionary) {
  NSDictionary *subDictionary = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
  NSString *type = [subDictionary objectForKey:@"type"];
  if (type == @"title") {
    currentTitle = [subDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
    if ([galleries objectForKey:currentTitle] == nil)
      [galleries setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:currentTitle];
  } else if (type == @"gallery" && currentTitle != nil)
    [[galleries objectForKey:currentTitle] addObject:subDictionary];
}
```

After this loop, `galleries` will contain keys of type `NSString` (with values of the titles), and corresponding objects of type `NSArray` (with values of the gallery `NSDictionarys`). Hopefully this is what you were going for.

Comment: Yes, my NSDictionary has values of NSDicitonary.

Comment: As you can see, after each title key comes a few other dictionaries that are not using the title key.  So, if 5 more dictionaries came after the title key dictionary, I want to put those 5 into a new array.  Then, if I see another title key, put those following NSDictionaries into an array.

Comment: I see. The only issue I can think of with that is that an NSDictionary is a key/value set that is not guaranteed to be in the order you might be expecting. Still, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am creating these dictionaries from XML, so I am pretty sure the order will stick.

Comment: Right, ultimately it should work fine. From a design aspect though, I'd change the format of the property list (XML) input. Anyway, I updated my answer, let me know if it's fitting.

Comment: Sure, I can change the format of the XML.  Do you have a suggestion for how I could do this better?

Comment: Hmm, the above code doesn't seem to be working with my structure...[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: If you can use it, `enumerateWithBlock:` is significantly more efficient for enumerating dictionaries.

Comment: fyi: `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`

Answer (score 14):

```
NSString *key;
for(key in someDictionary){
     NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, [someDictionary objectForKey: key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern Objective-C syntax:

```
NSMutableArray *things = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *stuff = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *bits = [NSMutableArray array];

[dictionaries enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [things addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"thing"]];
    [stuff addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"enclosing_object.stuff"]];
    [bits addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"bits"]];
}];
```